# When trying to use ng-transclude inside md-virtual-repeat I'm getting Illegal use of ng-transclude directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have created a directive which uses md-virtual-repeat-container component of angular material.

```
angular
      .module('MyApp')
      .directive('myDirective', function() {
          var template = document.getElementById("myDirective").innerHTML;
            return {
              replace: true,
              transclude: true,
              template: template,
              controllerAs: 'ctrl',
              controller: function() {
              this.items = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                  this.items.push(i);
              }
          }
        }
      });
```

My HTML

```
<div class="virtualRepeatdemoVerticalUsage" ng-app="MyApp" style="height:100%;width:800px">
  <my-directive>
    <span>Hello</span>
  </my-directive>
</div>
<script type="text/template" id="myDirective">
  <div style="height:100%; width:800px;">
    <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container" layout="column" style="background-color:yellow;height:100%;width:100%;min-height:0px">
      <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.items" class="repeated-item" style="background-color:orange;width:100%">
        {{item}}
        <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
      </div>
    </md-virtual-repeat-container>
  </div>  
</script>
```

The issue is when i am running this code i am getting

> Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent
>   directive that requires a transclusion found

Which makes sense since the ng-trasclude is becoming a part of md-virutal-repeat-container and it doesn't have ***trasclude*** property set.

**What I have tried so far:**

1. I have tried creating a separate child directive of my current directive and set ***transclude*** property to true but to add that child again I need to add ng-transclude to '*myDirective*' directive which brings me back to same issue.
2. I tried replacing the content in **prelink** function but the **md-virtual-repeat** removes the content before **prelink** and I am not able to access the content where i have to replace the transcluded element. Everything is fine in compile function but i don't have access to transcluded element in compile function.

**[Source of virtual repeat container](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/virtualRepeat/virtual-repeater.js)**

I have created a [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdMzGP?editors=1010) for this. Please play around with it and see if you can get through it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is working. I don't see any error in that pen.

Comment: @nextt1 My bad haven't saved the pen. Please check now.

Comment: Basically you want to use `virtual repeat container` as a `directive` right?

Comment: @nextt1 yes that's the basic idea.

Comment: md-virtual-repeat is usually needed if you have a very large data. I mean like 1000+ or 500+ rows. othrewise simple list will do the trick

Comment: Yes that is there I was just thinking if in any way i can make it reusable to my application. Thanks anyway @nextt1 I will see if i can make it work else will fallback to list.